# How can I fetch wasm file in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I just read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API) about fetching WebAssembly file using JavaScript

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('simple.wasm'), importObject)
.then(obj => obj.instance.exports.exported_func());
```

and

```
fetch('simple.wasm').then(response =>
  response.arrayBuffer()
).then(bytes =>
  WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
).then(results => {
  results.instance.exports.exported_func();
});
```

Is there an equivalent way to do so in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html)

Comment: What's wrong with just using the JavaScript code you have?

Comment: @UnholySheep do you mean using the same code in the `.ts` file?

Comment: Yes. TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, so all JavaScript code *should* work without modifications